# Unexpected result from data.table when looking in other table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to check if a value from a data table is present in another data table. However, I do not get a correct output:

```
> dt1 <- data.table(x=c(8,5,3), y=rnorm(3))
> dt2 <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=rnorm(5))
> setkey(dt1,x)
> setkey(dt2,a)
> 
> dt1
   x          y
1: 3 0.84929113
2: 5 1.33433818
3: 8 0.04170333
> dt2
   a           b
1: 1  2.00634915
2: 2 -1.53137195
3: 3 -1.49436741
4: 4 -1.66878993
5: 5 -0.06394713
> 
> dt1[,is_present_in_dt2:=nrow(dt2[x, nomatch=0L])]
> dt1
   x          y is_present_in_dt2
1: 3 0.84929113                 3
2: 5 1.33433818                 3
3: 8 0.04170333                 3

Expected result:


   x          y is_present_in_dt2
1: 3 0.84929113                 1
2: 5 1.33433818                 1
3: 8 0.04170333                 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is actually more straight forward than you are thinking. Think of it as sub-setting d1 with d2 in the i statement.

```
dt1 <- data.table(x=c(8,5,3), y=rnorm(3))
dt2 <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=rnorm(5))
setkey(dt1,x)
setkey(dt2,a)

dt1[dt2, presnt := 1] #Where they merge, make it a 1
dt1[!dt2, presnt := 0] #Where they don't merge, make it a 0
```

And the result:

```
   x          y presnt
1: 3 -0.6938894      1
2: 5  0.4891611      1
3: 8 -1.8227498      0
```

And another way to think of it:

```
overlap <- intersect(dt1$x,dt2$a)
dt1[x %in% overlap, present := 1]
dt1[!(x %in% overlap), present := 0]
```

The first way is much faster. The second way might help the understanding of the first way.

Comment: Nice one. Is the operator `:=` only a feature of data.table? Does it work as `=`?

Comment: `:=` is used to quickly "update" the `data.table`. Yes it is unique to `data.table`. It can be quite useful!

Comment: I read about 10 times your answer to really understand what it means. Something happened in my head when I understood that dt1[dt2, present := 1] was equivalent to dt1[dt2[x], present := 1]. Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1. You can first initialise with 0, which'll void the need for a second join: `dt1[, presnt :=0][dt2, presnt := 1]`